# What type of paper is used for mass-produced posters?

Tags: print-design, print-production, posters, paper

I'm looking to order prints of some artwork, and I'd like the paper to be the same or similar type used for mass-produced posters, such as movie/sports/music posters (by companies such as Trends International).  Based on the ones I own, it seems like they are are relatively lightweight and somewhat glossy.  However, since I don't know too much about paper weights and finishes, I'm really not sure.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The paper is, not surprisingly, called poster-paper. Usually around 100-130g. Coated on one or two sides (on one if you want the back side to be glued). It should be in version for outdoors and indoors. The indoors sometimes is satin not glossy as the poster can be showed behind glass.